# how to get these symbols on buttons in HTML

Tags: html, button, symbols

i am unable to find these symbols for HTML buttons.
please tell me how to put these symbols on HTML buttons.

[image]

Comment: And what's your HTML? Where are you stuck – if it's just that you "*can't find these symbols*" then you're asking us to find you an external resource (which is off-topic); having found the resource why would you be stuck adding the characters to a button?

Comment: You''ll find some but not all your symbols here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arrows/images.htm

Comment: Check out `https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/`:) Font awesome delivers easy ways to add certain icons to your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add arrow symbols to as text to button in HTML, you have several options.

1. Select a font that features arrows and use it.
2. Use Unicode symbols with the `&<identifier>;` syntax and use a code from [this page.](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp)

If a custom image is what you're after, download or locate the image you want to place on the button and apply the following css to your button, replacing the url with the one from the image.

```
.button {
    background-image: url('image/url/image.png');
}
```